# Apparent DNS problem in Ubuntu 17.04 in a VMWare VM

Tags: networking, dns, vmware

I’ve been running v.14.04 in VMWare Workstation v.12 (running on a Win10 Thinkpad) for about a year without any major problems.

I’m trying to get v.17.04 set up inside the same VMWare Workstation but am currently having two show-stopping problems. One is described below and I'll post the other one as a separate q:

I can’t access the internet using FireFox (or the browser that the Amazon app uses) from the 17.04 VM. I am using NAT translation for the VM’s network.

This seems to be a DNS problem: I can ping addresses on my LAN by IP address from terminal and can ping into the VM from a Win CMD window on the laptop. However, unlike my 14.04 VM, I can’t ping an external address (e.g. www.bbc.co.uk) by name from inside Terminal, I get “Name of service not known”. This is despite the fact that the Connection Information utility shows the same values for “Default route” and “Primary DNS” in both my 14.04 and 17.04 VMs.

So, what could be causing this DNS problem and how to fix it?

**Update:**  I should have mentioned a couple of things:  I get the same problem in a new install of 17.04 in VMWare on another machine; and I still get the problem if I configure the network setting for the VM as `Bridged` - I don't normally use that setting, but it enables me to see the numeric IP address of the DNS server as I'm used to seeing it on my LAN, and it is correct (namely 192.168.0.1, which is the IP of my DSL router).

Answer (score 0):

I found I could get DNS working by configuring the connection's IP4 settings manually.  Basically, on the IPv4 tab, I

- set the `Method` to Manual
- added an entry in the `Addresses` section, using the VMWare IP address of my connection, 192.168.32.130 as the address, 255.255.255.0 as the `Netmask` and the address of my LAN's router, 192.168.32.2 as the `Gateway`
- obtained the address of one of the DNS servers, 212.23.3.100, at my ISP, Zen, and entered it in the `DNS servers` box and restarted the connection.

After that, FireFox etc access the internet fine.  I gues the lingering question is why the `Automatic` setting apparently doesn't retrieve the DNS setting correctly.